# C++ pointer to vector vs pointer to vector elements

Tags: c++, pointers

small question about pointers to vectors to find out what makes more sense in this case (the matrices can be quite big):

```
typedef std::vector<double> Matrix;  

// Pointer to the whole vector
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<Matrix>> _matrices;
// or vec on stack and point to each element
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Matrix>> _matrices;
```

Is there a noticeable difference (except working with Matrix pointers vs Matrix references)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both make not much sense.

Comment: Vectors have an internal pointer pointing to the data they hold. So you don't need a pointer to the vector itself regardless how big the data is.

Comment: You don't need pointers here. Just write `typedef std::vector<double> Matrix;` and use `Matrix`, that's all. Or is this an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Don't you think `typedef`ing a vector to the name `Matrix` doesn't make sense either?

Comment: @NickyC it might be somewhat unusual, but why not?

Comment: @Jabberwocky The name is misleading. That's why.

Comment: Normally you need neither. `std::vector<Matrix>>` is good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vectors have an internal pointer pointing to the data they hold. So you don't need a pointer to the vector itself regardless how big the data is.

For example if you need to access the internal pointer you can get it like this:

```
// just for show, don't do this unless you absolutely must
Matrix* matrix = _matrices.data();
```

The main reason for having vectors of pointers it to leverage *polymorphism* but that isn't the case in your instance. Otherwise introducing pointers is redundant and less efficient.

The only possible reason I can think of where pointers to vectors does make sense is if you need to **share *ownership*** a vector through different components.

In this case a [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) could make sense:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Matrix>> shared_matrices;
```

But I would think that would be fairly rare.

Comment: So an std::vector<T> allocates on the heap, by default? (so a .push_back(ObjectX()) actually creates a "new ObjectX()") Or is it just working with pointers internally, but on the stack?

Comment: @Krck By *always*.

Comment: @Krck The vector itself is on the stack. But the vector just contains a couple of pointers. One of the internal pointers points to an **array** allocated on the heap. The vector's elements are stored as **values** in that heap-allocated array.

Comment: Can I put it this way? Reference semantics is that you **own** the allocation. Pointer semantics is that you **are** (or at least should be) the allocation itself. The std containers, std allocator, pmr::allocator is reference semantics, you just own things, you are passed by ref and can be moved around (if you are allowed by design). The pmr::memory_resource is pointer semantics, you are the allocation, passed by pointer.